# Fetching CPU usage and memory leak from the server

Tags: jmeter

How do I get CPU performance with JMETER.

My environment:

```
apache-jmeter-2.9
ServerAgent-2.2.1
Windows Server 2008 R2
```

The problem is, when the I run the server agent in the server and trying to fetch the data in jmeter UI the command prompt on the server shows error :

```
INFO    2014-01-06 12:34:15.255 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding UDP to 4444
INFO    2014-01-06 12:34:16.302 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding TCP to 4444
INFO    2014-01-06 12:34:16.302 [kg.apc.p] (): JP@GC Agent v2.2.0 started
INFO    2014-01-06 12:36:57.588 [kg.apc.p] (): Accepting new TCP connection
ERROR   2014-01-06 12:36:57.592 [kg.apc.p] (): Error executing command
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown command [4]: 'name'
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.processCommand(PerfMonMetricGetter
.java:87)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.processNextCommand(PerfMonMetricGe
tter.java:101)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.read(PerfMonWorker.java:210)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.processCommands(PerfMonWorker.java:97)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.AgentTool.processParams(AgentTool.java:72)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:63)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:175)
```

Comment: You didn't put `JmeterPlug.jar` in the bin folder.

Comment: where do I get this ?